# Accessing the values of a line in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a program that detect a line in a frame, and my question is: how can I access the values of the pixel forming this line  , I have the polar coordinates of the line : the angle and the distance to 0: here is my code to get the line position :

```
....................
cv::Canny(dilationResult,canny,50,200,3);
cv::HoughLines(canny,lineQ,1,CV_PI/180,200);
    for( size_t i = 0; i < lineQ.size(); i++ )
        {
          float rho = lineQ[i][0], theta = lineQ[i][1];
          cv::Point pt1, pt2;
          double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
          double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
          pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b));
          pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a));
          pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b));
          pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a));
          angle = atan2f((pt2.y-pt1.y),(pt2.x-pt1.x))*180.0/CV_PI;  // getting the angle of the lines 

         std::cout << "angle " << angle<< std::endl;
          line( mask, pt1, pt2, cv::Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
        }
```

and let say I got this frame 
[image: line]   how can I get the values of the lines ?

thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: What do you mean by the values? You want the coordinates of each pixel? What is your goal?

Comment: in the example above the values will all be 0 since the line is black and for that and also need the position !

Comment: You have rho and theta so you can use those to calculate the points on the line. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782873/houghlines-transform-in-opencv

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get each point on the line using [LineIterator](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#lineiterator). e.g. (assuming 3 channel image):

```
cv::LineIterator it(dilationResult, pt1, pt2, 8);
std::vector<cv::Vec3b> buf(it.count);
std::vector<cv::Point> points(it.count);

for(int i = 0; i < it.count; i++, ++it)
{
    buf[i] = *(const cv::Vec3b)*it;
    points[i] = it.pos();
}
```

Also, because you are using Canny, lines will have have two edges detected.

Answer (score 2):

to iterate over line pixels do it as B... shows.

Just to add: if you need line positions in subpixel accuracy you can parameterize the line with parameter alpha [0 to 1]:

```
cv::Point2f subpixel;
subpixel.x = alpha*pt1.x + (1.0f - alpha)*pt2.x
subpixel.y = alpha*pt1.y + (1.0f - alpha)*pt2.y
```