# OpenCV draw intersecting lines, where intersection area intensity is summed

Tags: c++, opencv, draw

Is there any way to draw on a single channel matrix in a way that the intensity of intersecting lines will be summed?
E.g. if the color of the line is 100, and I'm drawing a cross, I want to have intensity of 200 in the middle of the cross.
[image: this is what I get, using cv::line(mat, p1, p2, 50, 20, CV_AA);]

Comment: Do you really have only two lines that are perfectly horizontal and vertical? If so, then you can easily calculate the intersection. If not, is there a reason you don't want to draw two Mat's and add them? What code are you using to generate these lines?

Comment: I will actually draw a lot of lines.
I have set of lines, and I need to have them painted together (for later processing of the result image).
and I want to be able to know the intensity of pixels in the picture - that can be painted by several lines (van form an asterisk for example - and i need the middle of it to be the sum of lines intensity)

Comment: What about my other questions? I didn't ask them idly; the answers could indicate different solutions. For example, you can easily draw more than two lines using two Mat's and adding. Alternatively, you can use a line iterator if you have a lot of lines and you need more speed, but if those lines are more than one pixel wide and not perfectly horizontal/vertical, it could become complicated.

Comment: I see you edited your comment to add a bit more detail while I was typing my response, but it still seems the approach of iteratively adding new lines by summing the output image and the new line image would be simplest.

Comment: Thanks,
The only issue is that it will be a big time consuming.
since if sum 2 matrix, where the only change is in a little area (my lines are several pixels long (~ 50) and few pixels wide(~5).
Since I'm going to repeat this operation, I would like to have the fastest solution.

Comment: Then you're probably going to need to use the line iterator as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20605678/accessing-the-values-of-a-line-in-opencv.

Comment: Since you're drawing the lines, I'd assume you know the coordinates of the intersection as well. So, either draw a small filled in rectangle of appropriate colour, or perhaps just scale the intensity in that area by 2. That's assuming it's always a pair you draw, and you only want to highlight the intersection of this given pair. If you want to highlight all the intersections, i'd plot horizontal and vertical into separate images, and then add them together.

Comment: Since it is a line list that i read - I don't know what the intersections will be, if any.
I have tried to use matrix adding, but I get the same result.
my example code is:

  cv::Point s(p1.X, p1.Y );

  cv::Point e(p2.X , p2.Y );

  cv::line(mat, s, e, 100, 19, CV_AA);

        cv::Point s2(p3.X, p3.Y );

  cv::Point e2(p4.X , p4.Y );

  cv::line(mat, s2, e2, 100, 19, CV_AA);

  cv::addWeighted(mat,1, addlineMat,1, 0.0, resultMat);

I get is the same as before - intersection area is not summed, but equals to the maximum intensity.

Comment: Why are you using `addWeighted`? Just use `+`. You should also make sure that the type of the result Mat is large enough not to saturate. And please put your code in the question, it's very difficult to read in comments.

Comment: btw, the reason the intensities are not adding in your code is that you're drawing the second line to the original `mat` instead of `addlineMat`.

Comment: OK thanks.

Using "+=" operator for each line solved it.